Salesforce screen flow - Update record element works intermittently
I have a screen where I take the user input and save that value onto one of the fields on a Case record. On the next screen I pull the details of the same record and that's where I notice that sometimes I see the value getting pulled and sometimes it is just blank. Here is the snip of the flow -

Here in the snip above the Update Records element does the updating and then the Screen Incident Location & Equipment shows the info of that record.
The Screen element has an LWC Component and a display element. The LWC component pulls the updated record using the wire adaptor and the display element displays it on the flow screen. Here is the snip -

My question is whether the updating is happening right away or is it deferred? If it is deferred how do I make the update happen right away as the same record details are being populated in the next screen element?

The wire adapters use a client-side cache which improves performance but can lead to this sort of thing if the components in play do not all use the same mechanism. I am guessing that flow's update record isn't playing ball and does not use or notify the data services being used by the wire adapters. Importantly, the update record will have worked, but the wire adapter is not actually re-fetching the record data if the cache is still active.

Considering that the update of records and screens are loading one after the other, there is a possibility that the next screen may or may not load the latest values. Try these two workarounds if possible:
Workaround A:
Once the record is updated, instead of fetching the record using LWC, try using SOQL in the flow itself, and then use the screen component.
Update -> SOQL -> Screen
Workaround B:
This is more of a hack. If the purpose is just to display the updated values on the screen, store the values that are being updated in separate variables.Eg, on Account object if the field Name and Phone are getting updated, store them in a variable strName, strPhone and use these variables to display on the error screen.

Will have to try and find out if workaround B would work.
